# Multivariate Exponential Distribution in Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Is there a way to define a multivariate exponential distribution based on independent univariate exponential distributions (Akin to multinormal distribution):

```
MultivariateExponentialDistribution[lambda1, lambda2, lambda3] = {ExponentialDistribution[lambda1], ExponentialDistribution[lambda2], ExponentialDistribution[lambda3]}
```

I need this distribution to model a hidden Markov process where each state emits three values coming from different exponential distributions.

Right now I am solving this problem for each dimension independently (resulting in different transition matrices)

```
hmm1 = HiddenMarkovProcess[4, ExponentialDistribution[lambda1]]
hmm2 = HiddenMarkovProcess[4, ExponentialDistribution[lambda2]]
hmm3 = HiddenMarkovProcess[4, ExponentialDistribution[lambda3]]
```

My goal is:

```
hmm = HiddenMarkovProcess[4, MultivariateExponentialDistribution[lambda1, lambda2, lambda3]]
```

thanks

Hani

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dist = ProductDistribution[ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]1], ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]2], ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]3]];

data = TemporalData[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 100, 3}], {Range[100]}];

hmm = EstimatedProcess[data, HiddenMarkovProcess[4, dist]]
```

Comment: Thank you Alexey, that is right on the spot!